# Android: geolocation doesn't work anymore on some devices (since Jelly Bean (4.1.x) ?)

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I have got two apps on Google Play since several months. Since few weeks, I receive some emails from users who tell me that the app doesn't determine their location anymore. My app has not been updated before these problems.

The onLocationChanged delegate method is no more called on these devices.

It seems that the issue happens with the devices with Android 4.1.x and higher (Jelly Bean).

Note that on these devices which present the issue, it seems that the other apps which use the geolocation also do not work anymore ; just Google Maps still manages to geolocalize the user.

How to explain that geolocation does not work anymore on Android 4.1.x Jelly Bean and higher ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: It could have to do with the recent deprecation of the google maps android v1 API. Were you using that? As of March 18th you can no longer request new API keys. Google says old apps should work but who knows? Totally making things up here, just throwing ideas out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One of my two problematic apps (but just one) indeed includes the former version of Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong but it could have to do with the fact that if your app is using Google Maps Android API v2, your users now need to activate Location sources in two spots before it works:

1. Settings > Location access > GPS or Wifi
2. Accounts > Google > Location settings > Let Google apps access your location ON

If I deactivate the second, my app that uses the API no longer gets a location update.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, I set the Launcher in the settings to JellyBean 4.1 down from 4.2 and it works again. It must be something to do with the launcher restricting access to the GPS.